# Emulator for Game Boy that supports shortcut key to combo or special attack

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, emulator

I want to play [*Sailor Moon* for Nintendo Game Boy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sailor_Moon_video_games#Nintendo_Systems), but I don't have a real Game Boy.

Because the characters in *Sailor Moon* game have some special moves and I remembered that it was hard to do it, could you recommend a good emulator for Game Boy running on Windows that supports shortcut key to combo or special attack?

Which means when I press the button <kbd>A</kbd>, a special move will be created, and the super attack will blast the enemies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use any emulator, you just need to install [AHK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ahk/) or [any other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) key/mouse automation software.

Comment: Hi, Kokizzu. yes I have tried out AHK, but I don't know the code for key/mouse automation. Do you have any suggested lines of code?

Comment: Just study from this tutorial ^^ http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=34948

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It's the only GBA emulator I use and recommend:

[GBA Emulators for PC](http://techraze.com/gba-emulator-pc-free-download-windows-7-8-8-1)

Comment: Sorry, Bhargav Gupta. I am using an old PC running XP.